# How to group records with Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to group the same records at the database. My code:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, LastName, FullDateAlternateKey
FROM 
    ((AdventureWorksDW2012..FactInternetSales 
INNER JOIN 
    AdventureWorksDW2012..DimProduct ON FactInternetSales.ProductKey = DimProduct.ProductKey)
INNER JOIN 
    AdventureWorksDW2012..DimDate ON DimDate.DateKey = FactInternetSales.DueDateKey)
INNER JOIN 
    AdventureWorksDW2012..DimCustomer ON DimCustomer.CustomerKey = FactInternetSales.CustomerKey
WHERE 
    YEAR(FullDateAlternateKey) LIKE '2013' 
    AND MONTH(FullDateAlternateKey) LIKE '12'
```

What I get:

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eugene | Huang | 2013-12-22 |
| Eugene | Huang | 2013-12-22 |
| Eugene | Huang | 2013-12-22 |
| Eugene | Huang | 2013-12-22 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-22 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-22 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-11 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-11 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-12 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-12 |
| Jaclyn | Lu | 2013-12-01 |

I need to records would be like this:

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eugene | Huang | 2013-12-22 |
| Like | Lal | 2013-12-22 |

and so on.

If I add

```
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

I get this error:

> The "AdventureWorksDW2012...DimDate.FullDateAlternateKey" column is not allowed in the selection list because it is not contained in either the aggregate function or the GROUP BY sentence.

Comment: You've tagged `GROUP BY` here, but your query doesn't have one.  Have you omitted it in error?

Comment: On a different note, don't use syntax like `YEAR(FullDateAlternateKey) LIKE '2013'` in your `WHERE`; it isn't SARGable. Use proper date boundaries: `date >= {Start Date} AND date < {End Date}`.

Comment: Seems, in truth, you want the `MAX` `FullDateAlternateKey`.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; you aren't aggregating the column `FullDateAlternateKey`

Comment: Yes, I just need to add this column. Thank you all!

Comment: Add to what? The `GROUP BY`? Then what are you aggregating in? If you are grouping on *all" the columns and not aggregating you might as well `DISTINCT` to be more clear about your intent.

Comment: `YEAR(FullDateAlternateKey) LIKE '2013' `? `LIKE` is for pattern matching. And `YEAR` returns an integer, not a string. You merely want `YEAR(FullDateAlternateKey) = 2013`. But Larnu's suggestion to compare whole dates is even better. The parentheses in the `FROM` clause look weird. What are they for? Remove them. Then always qualify all columns with their tables when working with more than one table. `SELECT DimCustomer.FirstName, DimCustomer.LastName, DimDate.FullDateAlternateKey`. The query would become more readabe with table aliases.

Comment: Why is Jaclyn Lu not in the desired results? Or is one row what "and so on" means? You want the maximum date per name, right? Or does "and so on" mean you want all other dates, too? `select distinct ...`?

Answer (score 3):

You want the maximum date per FirstName and LastName, so you `GROUP BY FirstName, LastName` and select `MAX(FullDateAlternateKey)`. (FullDateAlternateKey is a strange name for a date by the way.)

The join to `DimProduct` seems superfluous. The date condition can be improved.

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, MAX(d.fulldatealternatekey)
FROM adventureworksdw2012.factinternetsales fis
JOIN adventureworksdw2012.dimcustomer c ON c.customerkey = fis.customerkey
JOIN adventureworksdw2012.dimdate d ON d.datekey = fis.duedatekey
WHERE d.fulldatealternatekey >= '2013-12-01'
  AND d.fulldatealternatekey < '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname
ORDER BY c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

Comment: Recommend adding ```CustomerKey``` to the ```GROUP BY``` since people can have the same names.

Comment: Yep, this sounds like a good idea.